# Дан текст. Найти числа и вычислить их вычитание Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Дан текст:

```
Пушкин 1799-1837
Лермонтов 1814-1841
```

Нужно посчитать года жизни.

Comment: С чем у возникли затруднения?

Comment: `abs(1799-1837)` или просто `1837-1799`

Answer (score 2):

Предположу, что заданием будет разбор текста и подсчет лет, тогда:

```
text = """\
Пушкин 1799-1837
Лермонтов 1814-1841
"""

for line in text.splitlines():
    name, age = line.split()
    start, end = map(int, age.split('-'))

    print('{}, {} лет'.format(name, end - start))
```

---

А если нужно через регулярки, тогда можно сделать так:

```
import re

for name, start, end in re.findall(r'(\w+) (\d+)-(\d+)', text):
    print('{}, {} лет'.format(name, int(end) - int(start)))
```

Работает это так: `re.findall` вернет список `[('Пушкин', '1799', '1837'), ('Лермонтов', '1814', '1841')]`, а в цикле на каждой итерации каждый его элемент разложится по переменным `name`, `start`, `end`. А т.к. результатом будет строки, то числа перед вычитанием нужно будет в `int` привести.

---

Результат:

```
Пушкин, 38 лет
Лермонтов, 27 лет
```

Comment: ещё: `print(re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{4})', lambda m: str(-operator.sub(*map(int, m.groups()))), text))`